# Automatizar pulsaciones de tecla para controlar un juego en Python?

Tags: python

estoy intentando controlar un juego(Minecraft) o cualquier juego, con pulsaciones de teclado automatizado.

El problema es que el juego no responde a los eventos simulados del teclado. Los juegos ignoran las pulsaciones de teclas automatizadas.

Puse estos dos códigos para explicar el asunto.

*Cabe destacar que los códigos no se ejecutan en la consola de Python*

---

-En este primer código, en el chat de juego que escriba 'hola' automáticamente y una sola vez

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import Time 

# Primer código
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.write ('Hola')
    break
```

---

-En este segundo código, se mantendrá precionado la letra 'w' por lo que el personaje del juego debería caminar hacia delante

```
# Segundo código
while True:
    time.sleep(0.003)
    pyautogui.press("w")
    pyautogui.write ('w')
```

---

Estos códigos funcionan en cualquier editor de texto, caja de texto, bloc de notas, etc.
Pero se ignoran en cualquier juego.

Apreciaría cualquier tipo de ayuda. Si es posible, con ejemplos concretos de código, alguna librería, información.

Muchas gracias y un saludo!!

Comment: Sería un excelente proyecto con un MCU programable con MicroPython. Puedes conectar el MCU al puerto USB, emulando un teclado. Lo pones unos botoncitos y lo programas para enviar secuencias de teclas. Puedes usar un ESP8266 o ESP32.

Comment: Este proyecto usa un Arduino y C++ para emular un teclado. Te puede servir de inspiración: [Cómo emular un teclado o un ratón con Arduino](https://www.luisllamas.es/como-emular-un-teclado-o-un-raton-con-arduino/)

Comment: Acaso no es `pyautogui.press("w")`?

Comment: Candid Moe gracias por la información!

Comment: Christian si, con esa función queda mejor!

Comment: Y no te funciona?

Comment: Solo en editor de texto, caja de texto. En el juego no funciona o mejor dicho lo ignora.

Comment: Una vez hice unscript para poder jugar al dinosaurio de Chrome y tuve tu mismo problema,al final opte por hacer mi juego propio. No he encontrado la solución y no sé si te podre ayudar

Comment: buscando otra cosa encontré tu consulta, no se si aún seguirás interesado pero eso que pretendes hacer, si se puede hacer, pero con otro "lenguaje", de hecho yo tengo varios scripts que he usado incluso en servidores públicos de MC.
Por si te es de interés, busca en Google sobre "AutoHotKey" es con lo que creo los scripts y los he usado en varios juegos no solo Minecraft.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que deberías probar con otras funciones de pyautogui. Creo que para lo que estas buscando necesitas pyautogui.keyDown("w"), pero recuerda que debes ejecutar un keyUp("w") en algún momento para recuperar el control del teclado.